# cannot cast Func<T1, T2<U>> to Func<T1, T2<V>> with V : U

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, covariance

I have a method returning `Func<ConstructorInfo, MyDelegate<T>>` where `MyDelegate`is a generic (covariant) delegate. Now I want to assign the result of this method to a variable of type `Func<ConstructorInfo, MyDelegate<U>>` where `U` is a baseclass from `T` (T : U). But I get `InvalidCastException`. Is this because `Func` is not covariant (at least in .NET 3.5) or how may I fix this?

EDIT some code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public delegate T MyDelegate<out T>(params object[] args);

class GenericTypeFactory
{
    public static MyDelegate<T> GetActivator<T>(ConstructorInfo ctor) 
    { 
            // make a NewExpression that calls the ctor with the args we
            // just created
            var newExp = Expression.New(ctor);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(MyDelegate<T>), newExp);
            var compiledExpression = (MyDelegate<T>)lambda.Compile();
            return compiledExpression;
    }
}
```

And in my main-class:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class MyClass {
    private Func<ConstructorInfo, MyDelegate<T>> createLambdaExpression<T>()
    {
        // this Func is only introduced to ensure name-safety when
        // refactoring the GenericTypeFactor.GetActivator-method 
        // (changing params, other name, ...) we could also use
        // Reflection to get this method by its name the generic-type
        // argument <T> is only a placeholder
        Func<ConstructorInfo, Delegate> myFunc = 
            GenericTypeFactory.GetActivator<T>;

        MethodInfo method = myFunc.Method;
        // set the params for the method we obtained above
        var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ConstructorInfo), "ctor");
        // call the method with its params
        var call = Expression.Call(method, paramExp);                
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<ConstructorInfo, MyDelegate<T>>>(
                call, 
                paramExp)
            .Compile();
    }

    void DoSomeThing<T>()
    {
        Type customType = typeof(T); // not really, but for simplicity
        // type T is only a dummy-type (replaced in next line)
        Func<Delegate> myFunc = this.createLambdaExpression<T>; 
        MethodInfo method = 
            myFunc.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
            .MakeGenericMethod(customType);
        var getActivator = (Func<ConstructorInfo, MyDelegate<T>>)
            method.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you *using* .NET 3.5? It would really help if you'd give more details of your environment, and a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Yeap, I´m using 3.5. Just wait a bit, I have to build short test-program...

Comment: @JonSkeet It doesn't have anything to do with the .NET Framework version.

Comment: Covariance is 4.0, isn't it?

Comment: @Mert: It may or it may not. Once we've got a short but complete example, we can find out.

Comment: How is `MyClass` covariant if you're using .NET 3.5? (I know the CLR v2 supports covariance, but I'm surprised you can use it even with a C# 4 compiler when targeting .NET 3.5... and `Func<...>` definitely wasn't covariant in .NET 3.5.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm convinced now.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Ofc. MyClass is no class, its a covariant delegate.

Comment: Are `T` and `U` *inputs* to the delegate `MyClass` or *outputs*? Also, your title and question seem to disagree on the ordering of `T` and `U` (or is it `U` and `V`?)

Comment: The same question still applies, effectively: how is it a covariant delegate if you're using .NET 3.5? (If you're building against .NET 3.5, I'm somewhat surprised that it compiles. But even if it does, `Func` won't be covariant.)

Comment: And this still isn't a short but complete program.

Comment: @JonSkeet Compiles and runs so far...

Comment: Not *just* the code you've given. There's no class declaration, for example. If you'd posted a short but complete program, I'd be able to copy, paste, compile. I can't, because you've posted three snippets instead.

Comment: Compiling code here http://ideone.com/9sNRIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m still not sure why it did not work the way I posted above. Now I found another way, that at least works (although its not my favourite). For that I just cast the result of my createLambdaExpression-method to a Delegate instead of the concrete Func and call its DynamicInvoke-method. This of course is not optimal in consideration of performance but as I cache all my activators I just have to call it once instead of allways I need a new instance of the specific type.

```
Func<Delegate> myFunc = this.createLambdaExpression<T>;
MethodInfo method = myFunc.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(customType);
var getActivator = (Delegate)method.Invoke(this, null);
var activator = (Delegate)getActivator.DynamicInvoke(new[] { ctor });
```

Finally I call `((ObjectActivator<T>) activator)()` which will return a new instance of the type customType.